# esp32 debug with ft2232hl fail

Tags: esp32, ftdi

i'm trying to setup eclipse ide for debug esp-wroom-32 board with ftdi ft2232hl ic. I read many documentation and this tutorial https://mcuoneclipse.com/2019/10/20/jtag-debugging-the-esp32-with-ft2232-and-openocd/.
I bought the same ft2232hl green board and i can run the explained openocd commands with the same output.

In eclipse i can build projects and run the debugger but it only flash the target.
I create the same FT2232HL.cfg file from tutorial and write the follow command in debug configuration:
-s ${openocd_path}/share/openocd/scripts -f interface/ftdi/myFT2232HL.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg

i only changed the frequency from 200 Khz to 20000 Khz because with 200 eclipse launch an error.
When i run the debug the target is programmed but debug not run.
This is the output:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.10.0-esp32-20210401 (2021-04-01-15:46)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 20000 kHz

WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
Flashing C:/Users/Marco/eclipse_workspace_esp32/gatt_server_test2/build/partition_table/partition-table.bin at 0x8000
Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
Info : ftdi: if you experience problems at higher adapter clocks, try the command "ftdi_tdo_sample_edge falling"
Info : clock speed 20000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : esp32.cpu0: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Core was reset.
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40127FBE, debug_reason=00000000
Info : Set GDB target to 'esp32.cpu0'
Info : esp32.cpu1: Target halted, PC=0x40127FBE, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu0: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x500000CF, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu1: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : Flash mapping 0: 0x10020 -> 0x3f400020, 89 KB
Info : Flash mapping 1: 0x30020 -> 0x400d0020, 355 KB
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : Auto-detected flash bank 'esp32.cpu0.flash' size 4096 KB
Info : Using flash bank 'esp32.cpu0.flash' size 4096 KB
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : Flash mapping 0: 0x10020 -> 0x3f400020, 89 KB
Info : Flash mapping 1: 0x30020 -> 0x400d0020, 355 KB
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : Auto-detected flash bank 'esp32.cpu1.flash' size 4096 KB
Info : Using flash bank 'esp32.cpu1.flash' size 4096 KB
** Programming Started **
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : PROF: Data transferred in 29.921 ms @ 133.685 KB/s
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
Info : PROF: Data transferred in 31.914 ms @ 94.0026 KB/s
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
** Verified OK **
** Flashing done for partition_table/partition-table.bin **
Flashing C:/Users/Marco/eclipse_workspace_esp32/gatt_server_test2/build/bootloader/bootloader.bin at 0x1000
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : esp32.cpu0: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x500000CF, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu1: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
** Programming Started **
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : PROF: Data transferred in 109.502 ms @ 255.703 KB/s
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
Info : PROF: Data transferred in 109.394 ms @ 223.533 KB/s
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
** Verified OK **
** Flashing done for bootloader/bootloader.bin **
Flashing C:/Users/Marco/eclipse_workspace_esp32/gatt_server_test2/build/gatt_server_demos.bin at 0x10000
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : esp32.cpu0: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x500000CF, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu1: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
** Programming Started **
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
Info : PROF: Data transferred in 1950.64 ms @ 282.984 KB/s
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
Info : PROF: Data transferred in 2145.99 ms @ 256.852 KB/s
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x40091C2A, debug_reason=00000001
** Verified OK **
** Flashing done for gatt_server_demos.bin **
** Resetting Target **
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu0 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : JTAG tap: esp32.cpu1 tap/device found: 0x120034e5 (mfg: 0x272 (Tensilica), part: 0x2003, ver: 0x1)
Info : esp32.cpu0: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu0: Target halted, PC=0x500000CF, debug_reason=00000000
Info : esp32.cpu0: Core was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Debug controller was reset.
Info : esp32.cpu1: Core was reset.
0
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

after this the target is corrected programmed.
What's wrong?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: i don't know why but using usb hub it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).